# Python Loop through dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a file that I wish to parse. It has data in the json format, but the file is not a json file. I want to loop through the file, and pull out the ID where totalReplyCount is greater than 0.

```
  {  "totalReplyCount": 0,
       "newLevel":{ 
           "main":{  
              "url":"http://www.someURL.com",
              "name":"Ronald Whitlock",
              "timestamp":"2016-07-26T01:22:03.000Z",
              "text":"something great"
              },
       "id":"z12wcjdxfqvhif5ee22ys5ejzva2j5zxh04"
    }
},
    {  "totalReplyCount": 4,
        "newLevel":{ 
           "main":{  
              "url":"http://www.someUR2L.com",
              "name":"other name",
              "timestamp":"2016-07-26T01:22:03.000Z",
              "text":"something else great"
             },
       "id":"kjsdbesd2wd2eedd23rf3r3r2e2dwe2edsd"
    }
},
```

My initial attempt was to do the following

```
def readCsv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvFile:
        for row in csvFile["totalReplyCount"]:
            print row
```

but I get an error stating

> TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I know this is just an attempt at printing and not doing what I want to do, but I am a novice at python and lost as to what I am doing wrong. What is the correct way to do this? My end result should look like this for the ids:

```
['insdisndiwneien23e2es', 'lsndion2ei2esdsd',....]
```

*EDIT 1- 7/26/16*

I saw that I made a mistake in my formatting when I copied the code (it was late, I was tired..). I switched it to a proper format that is more like JSON. This new edit properly matches file I am parsing. I then tried to parse it with JSON, and got the `ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line X column 1`:, where line X is the end of the line.

```
 def readCsv(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            data=json.load(file)
            pprint(data)
```

I also tried DictReader, and got a `KeyError: 'totalReplyCount'`. Is the dictionary un-ordered?

*EDIT 2 -7/27/16*

After taking a break, coming back to it, and thinking it over, I realized that what I have (after proper massaging of the data) is a CSV file, that contains a proper JSON object on each line. So, I have to parse the CSV file, then parse each line which is a top level, whole and complete JSON object. The code I used to try and parse this is below but all I get is the first string character, an open curly brace '{'  :

```
def readCsv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
            for item in row:
                print item[0]
```

I am guessing that the DictReader is converting the json object to a string, and that is why I am only getting a curly brace as opposed to the first key. If I was to do `print item[0:5]` I would get a mish mash of the first 4 characters in an un-ordered fashion on each line, which I assume is because the format has turned into an un-ordered list? I think I understand my problem a little bit better, but still wrapping my head around the data structures and the methods used to parse them. What am I missing?

Comment: You are trying to use `[<string>]` on a file object it doesnt support it. Also the data you are reading does not look like a csv.

Comment: How did this abomination of a file even come into existence? It's so broken, I'm not sure how you intend to parse it at all.

Comment: You only want to get the ids? Nothing else?

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't valid json? It looks like it might be, if you are only posting a part of it, are you? Whatever the case, the CSV module is definitely not what you are going to need.

Comment: @Rawing - yes this is an abomination. It is what it is. I only want the ID's where the totalReplyCount is greater than zero.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I am not using the CSV module, I just gave the file the variable name csvFile because the values I want to read are comma separated as shown. Each "object" is on its own line, I just expanded it for readability.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the question and all the above answers, please check if this is useful to you.

I have considered input file as simple file not as csv or json file.

Flow of code is as follow:

- Open and read a file in reverse order.
- Search for ID in line. Extract ID and store in temp variable.
- Go on reading file line by line and search totalReplyCount.
- Once you got totalReplyCount, check it if it greater than 0.
- If yes, then store temp ID in id_list and re-initialize temp variable.

> ```
> import re
> tmp_id_to_store = ''
> id_list = []
> for line in reversed(open("a.txt").readlines()):
>     m = re.search('"id":"(\w+)"', line.rstrip())
>     if m:
>         tmp_id_to_store = m.group(1)
>     n = re.search('{  "totalReplyCount": (\d+),', line.rstrip())
>     if n:
>         fou = n.group(1)
>         if int(fou) > 0:
>             id_list.append(tmp_id_to_store)
>             tmp_id_to_store = ''
> print id_list
> ```

More check points can be added.

Answer (score 0):

As the error stated, Your `csvFile` is a `file` object, it is not a `dict` object, so you can't get an item out of it.

if your `csvFile` is in CSV format, you can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read each line of the csv into a dict :

```
import csv
with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print row['totalReplyCount']
```

note the `DictReader` method from the csv module, it will read your csv line and parse it into dict object

Comment: His input file however looks more like badly formed json.

Comment: @PaulRooney  yeah I just suppose that the file is in the correct csv format since he mentioned the file is not in json format

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is JSON why not just use the JSON library to parse it and then run a for loop over that data. Then it is just a matter of iterating over the keys and extracting data.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data)
```

[Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Look at Justin Peel's answer. It should help.

Comment: I did try iterating over the data in json, but got errors because it is not in the proper json format. I tried to parse the data and write to a file, but the error I got was TypeError: Expected a character buffer object...

Comment: @unseen_damage Are you sure your JSON is formatted correctly? Try using this to check first: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: The json is not formatted properly, although it is close to json. The file output is basically like such:
`{ item: 0, { item 2: {item 3: xxx, item4: xxx} item5: xxx } },
{ item: 0, { item 2: {item 3: xxx, item4: xxx} item5: xxx } }`,

Answer (score 0):

Parsing values from a JSON file in Python , this link has it all @ [Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python) via stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shell one-liner, should solve your problem, though it's not python.

```
egrep -o '"(?:totalReplyCount|id)":(.*?)$' filename | awk '/totalReplyCount/ {if ($2+0 > 0) {getline; print}}' | cut -d: -f2
```

output:

```
"kjsdbesd2wd2eedd23rf3r3r2e2dwe2edsd"
```